# Allow badges to be seen on the app

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, ios-app

I am one of those people who likes seeing what badges and accomplishments users (especially new users) have done.

I am also one of those people who uses the iOS app for SE because it is easier.

However, unfortunately I can't combine these two things! So I think we should!

In short, please can we allow users to see other users' badges while on the app?